# Cannot change the connectionstring with Entity Framework 4.1 code first

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, connection-string, ef-code-first

I am having trouble changing the connection string used by entity framework code first for my project.  I created a MVC3 project and then added two projects, DomainClasses and DataAccess.

The DomainClasses project has one class file named Classes.cs with one class:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

The DataAccess project has one class file named PLNQDB.cs with one class:

```
public class PLNQDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I have a reference to each of these projects inmy MVC project and everything builds fine and runs and even creates the database file that I am able to save to and retrieve data from.

When running the project I can see in the Autos window the connection string being used under this.db.base.Database.Connection.base.ConnectionString =

```
"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PLNQ.DataAccess.PLNQDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

My question is how do I override this autogenerated connectionstring to use my remote server.  I have added a connection string to the web.config file of the MVC project.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="Data Source=255.255.255.255;Initial Catalog=PLNQ;User ID=blah;Password=blah"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

but everytime I run the project it still uses the auto generated connectionstring.  I have also tried adding App.config files with the same connection string in both the DataAccess and DomainClasses projects.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are couple of options

1 You need to name the connection string that matches the your `DbContext` class name.

eg

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PLNQDB"
         connectionString="Data Source=255.255.255.255;Initial Catalog=PLNQ;User ID=blah;Password=blah"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

2 In your `DbContext` constructor call the base class constructor with the connection string name

```
public class PLNQDB : DbContext
{
    public PLNQDB():base("ApplicationServices"){}

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```